# How to use raylib on Manjaro?

Tags: c++, raylib

I wanna use raylib and I just installed Manjaro (KDE) on my laptop.

If I recall correctly I'm supposed to **Install** raylib from the **AUR**.

And that's what I did. I installed this: https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/raylib/

And everything went great but **how do I use it?**

Like from Windows I just copied the **Sample** and I worked from there. How do I do that now?

Thank you all!

**Edit:** Solved it, just open the terminal and type the following:

`cc main.c -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11`

Source: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-GNU-Linux#the-simplest-possible-build-command

Comment: So I can just simply make a new file and just `#include <raylib.h>` but now I have another problem. How do I build it?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, the solution should be posted as an Answer below, not edited into the question.